# How to determine if Tomcat is really running in windows

Tags: tomcat

I have a situation on my server with Tomcat, where Tomcat is no more running, but in the service list it is still set as a running service.

However, when I restart the service everything is fine.

So, I wish to write a .bat task which should check if Tomcat is in real running.
I tried to check the status in the Service list, but as I mentioned before, even if in the status list Tomcat is running I still have to restart the service.

Is there a way to be really sure the state of Tomcat?

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell to send an http request to Tomcat and see if it responds.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://localhost:8080/"
```

`$response.StatusCode` will be `200` if Tomcat is running and the default servlet is configured.